# smallest constant $c$ for which: $|x^k - y^k| < c \cdot |x - y|$, with $x,y < 1/2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, contraction-operator

Let $k \in \{2,3,\dots\}, a \in [0,1/2)$ and $x,y \in [0,a)$.

I haven't really shown it but am $99\%$ certain the following holds following inequality holds:
$$
|x^k - y^k| < |x - y|,
$$
But I am looking for a constant $c < 1$ in function of $k$ and $a$ s.t.:
$$
|x^k - y^k| < c|x - y|.
$$

Comment: Find a bound on $(d/dx)(x^k)$ on your interval.

Comment: That bound is $k \cdot a^{k-1}$, which means that we have $|x^k - y^k| \leq k \cdot a^{k-1} |x-y|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think about [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) applied for $f(x)=x^k$. I.e.
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|f'(\varepsilon)\right||x-y|$$
where $\varepsilon \in (x,y) \subset[0,a)$ (assuming $x<y$) of course.

Comment: I think I got it by indeed a method based on your hint (see the comments) :) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

$$x^k-y^k = (x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+....+y^{k-1})<(x-y)k\Big({1\over 2}\Big) ^{k-1}$$
so $c\leq k\Big({1\over 2}\Big) ^{k-1}$